# Getting device orientation in UIAutomation

Tags: ios, orientation, ios-ui-automation, device-orientation

I am writing automation test for my program and wish to automate the device orientation as well... I am using the below code to set an orientation to a device,

```
UIATarget.localTarget().setDeviceOrientation(UIA_DEVICE_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPERIGHT);
```

but I also wish to get the present orientation of the device. I couldn't find any getDeviceOrientation() method to get the orientation.

Comment: Not a duplicate, the question regards UIAutomation testing. I added the tag.

Comment: Am aware of this... but doesn't seem to work with UIATarget or in a .js file for test automation of ios

Comment: thanks hwaxxer for adding the tag for me...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
var orientation = UIATarget.localTarget().deviceOrientation()
```

From the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Reference/UIATargetClassReference/UIATargetClass/UIATargetClass.html):

> **deviceOrientation**
>
> Discussion
>
> The returned value is a constant that represents the physical orientation of the device and may be different from the current orientation of your app’s user interface. The possible values are as follows:

```
UIA_DEVICE_ORIENTATION_UNKNOWN
UIA_DEVICE_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT
UIA_DEVICE_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT_UPSIDEDOWN
UIA_DEVICE_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPELEFT
UIA_DEVICE_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPERIGHT
UIA_DEVICE_ORIENTATION_FACEUP
UIA_DEVICE_ORIENTATION_FACEDOWN
```

---

### EDIT

Device orientation is probably not available on the simulator. It's better to use `interfaceOrientation()` on the `UIAApplication` object instead.

```
var target = UIATarget.localTarget();
var app = target.frontMostApp();
var orientation = app.interfaceOrientation();

if (orientation == UIA_INTERFACE_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT || orientation == UIA_INTERFACE_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT_UPSIDEDOWN) {
    UIALogger.logDebug("Portrait");
} else if (orientation == UIA_INTERFACE_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPELEFT || orientation == UIA_INTERFACE_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPERIGHT) {
    UIALogger.logDebug("Landscape");    
}
```

[This guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/UsingtheAutomationInstrument/UsingtheAutomationInstrument.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004652-CH20) is pretty good.

Comment: Actually, `deviceOrientation()` works just fine on the simulator. I was using it two minutes ago. :)

Comment: @JonathanPenn That's odd. I'm getting wrong results for `deviceOrientation()` but correct results for `interfaceOrientation()` running on iPad/iPhone simulator (iOS 6, Instruments 4.5). It **does** however work if I call `-setDeviceOrientation`, in which case the `interfaceOrientation()` is incorrect. Sigh..

Comment: Same at hwaxxer, instruments is definitely a bloo** piece of sh**